# Subdomain of localhost is not working. Apache 2.4.25 (Debian) Server at subdomain.localhost Port 80

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, webserver, apache-virtualhost

Apache 2.4.25 (Debian) Server at Port 80: Subdomain of localhost is not working

localhost **is** working.

localhost/site1 **is** also working.

site1.localhost is **not** working

Changed **DocumentRoot** from `/var/www/html` to `/home/me/public_html`

In public_html directory, I created two directories, site1, site2

public_html directory has permissions:

```
rwxr-xr-x  2 me me
```

Configurations:

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       debian
127.0.0.1       site1.localhost

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    <Directory /home/me/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted          
    </Directory>

/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site1.localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/me/public_html/site1
</VirtualHost>
```

ste1.localhost returns:

403 Forbidden: Apache 2.4.25 (Debian) Server at **site1.localhost** Port 80

```
$ sudo apache2ctl -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost site1.localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost site2.localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="me" id=1000
Group: name="www-data" id=33


$ ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1583 Sep 24 23:54 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6338 Apr  5 14:32 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  103 Sep 24 11:03 site1.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  117 Sep 23 19:31 site2.conf


 $ ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
     total 0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Sep  5 12:13 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Sep 23 19:49 site1.conf -> ../sites-available/site1.conf
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Sep 23 19:49 site2.conf -> ../sites-available/site2.conf
```

Comment: Add the output of `apache2ctl -S` to your question. (possibly you need to leave out the `2` if it doesn't work)

Comment: So what is the name of the (first) site `site1` or `site1.localhost`?

Comment: @ctrl Edited it to add the **domain name configuration**.

Comment: @wurtel Can you please make it little more clear about **what I should try**.

Comment: It's not something you have to "try", it's something you just have to "do". Run the command `apache2ctl -S` as root, and edit your question to add the output of that command.

Comment: @wurtel Sir: Ran it and added the output to the question

Comment: 1. Have you put an `index.html` file into the  `DocumentRoot` for `site1.localhost`? 2. What does the Apache2 access and error logfiles tell you about the failure?

Comment: `sites-available` or `sites-enabled`, what is the difference? Are you editing the correct one?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Added `sites-available` also to the question

Comment: @roaima Yes, I added an `index.html` file to `DocumentRoot` file `public_html`. And, `/var/log/apache2/error.log` is empty

Comment: You did restart/reload Apache after adding the subsidiary vHost, `site1.localhost`?

Comment: @roaima Yes sir. I did.